# PTZ Security Camera Stuck in a Tour

Tags: security

I have an outdoor PTZ Dome Camera of unknown manufacturer but it has a type number sticker saying,  NG4RT-42718. It came with CMS V3.1.0.8 software. This seemed to drive the camera adequately until I set up a "Tour", ie. sequentially cycle through a number of preset PTZ settings.  Unfortunately, I then discovered that not only, was it not possible to stop this tour but the ebay seller no longer had an account! I have googled everywhere unsuccessfully searching for a possible reset switch or other solution. I tried using the tinyCam Monitor app to read the manf/model data but that drew a blank.

Further inf:
[image: Camera][image: Internal PCB]

re. Camers pic:
The label seems to pass for a user manual, the QR code links to the XM Eye app. The green dot under the lens is not a button, its function is unclear. There are no holes to access an internal reset button and the  wire tail fitted to some cameras in lieu of a button (strip sleeving and twist together!) is not provided. The RS485 port provided on some cameras is also not fitted to this one. If it had been then a DIL switch would have been present behind the window under the lens.

In one post I discovered it was states that XM Eye had deleted a stored Position that couldn't be deleted with the supplied software, presumably CMS, no such luck for me. Since posting, I have discovered that neither CMS or VMS, a poor substitute, can delete a stored Position or a Tour.

I then opened the case and found the pcb, no reset button here. However there are 2 empty sockets. At a guess, I'd hazzard the 5 pin socket is for the RS485 option and the 3 pin socket might be a reset button. Having recently fried a pc mobo by shorting the wrong pins to secet the bios, I am loathe to experiment with this.

More Stuff:
I have noticed an interesting spot on the pc board. At the bottom of the board, next to nect to the white plug with yellow and green wires is a pair of oversize pads that might just be the reset switch. Using a meter, between the 2 pads appears to be a high value capacitor and between each pad a V+ appears to be diode or transistor junction, pads to ground is OC. Can anyone confirm that this is a reset point?

Even if it is there is another problem. To perform a reset would require the pads to be shorted for perhaps up to 30s however the moment I power up the cameras it will start performing its tour. This could be overcome by soldering wires to the pads and shorting these, but my soldering equipment predates SMT, so I need to retire my trusty Weller and invest in a SMT rework station, is this possible piece of junk worth it?

Oh, btw, the QR code on the chip is a very long number.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: It might help if you edited the question to include photos of the device, especially including any labels on it. Does it have any buttons? Is there a tiny hole in it which you might stick a paperclip through?